# Pass for loop variable to shell function in makefile

Tags: makefile

How can I pass the value of variable `i` below to the `echo.sh` script inside the shell section?

```
loop:
    for i in 3 2 1; do \
        echo "var i = $$i"; \
        echo $(shell echo.sh $$i); \
    done
```

`echo.sh` could simply be:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
```

The output shows

```
for i in 3 2 1; do \
        echo "var i = $i"; \
        echo ; \
    done
var i = 3

var i = 2

var i = 1
```

The tricky part is to be able to pass $i to the $(shell ...) makefile function. I haven't been able to figure it out so far.

Thanks

EDIT: Added `echo` to the `$(shell ...` line and updated the output. It's trying to run a command. Original question still stands.

Comment: It's complaining that `echo.sh` doesn't exist at all, for starters.

Comment: Updated to fix the missing command. Original question still stands though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `shell` call, not only is it not necessary here, it will be expanded and called before the rest of the commands are even sent to the shell.

```
loop:
    for i in 3 2 1; do \
        echo "var i = $$i"; \
        ./echo.sh $$i; \
    done
```

Comment: I realise that this would work in my simplistic example but the question is really about how to get the loop variable `$i` to be expanded inside a makefile shell function `$(shell ... $$i)`

Comment: @Alkaline I can't see why you would want to do that, and in any case make functions are expanded **once** before the recipe is sent to the shell, make has no way of knowing it's inside a shell loop. If you really need to do this you'll probably need to use make's `foreach` function.

Comment: Make's `foreach` is more suited to creating strings than executing code. But I'm now getting the impression that I'm asking too much of make. I'll mark your answer as it's really about not doing too complex stuff in make, like doing variable expansion inside make functions.

Comment: @Alkaline It's not that you're asking to much, it's that without a real world example of what you're trying to do it's hard to come up with a solution. For what it's worth I *think* `$(foreach i, 1 2 3, $(shell ./echo.sh $i))` will do something similar to what you are looking for, but if that's the case then I still don't see how this could be useful as-is.